# elegant way to get a variables limit

Tags: c++, coding-style, numeric-limits

is there an better way to set a variables to one of its limits than

```
varname = std::numeric_limits<decltype(varname)>::max();
```

especially when initializing

```
int64_t varname = std::numeric_limits<decltype(varname)>::max();
```

I normally do not want to use the type in such expressions since its easy to miss this if type is changed.

Comment: I'd install a variable template: `template <typename T> constexpr T max_val = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();` and then use `auto v = max_val<int64_t>;`. In C++17 I'd make the template `inline` and stick it in a header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re

> **”** I normally do not want to use the type in such expressions since its easy to miss this if type is changed.

that's easy:

```
auto varname = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max();
```

You can reduce the verbosity of `std::numeric_limits` in many ways, e.g. by an template alias or by defining a function template.

```
template< class Type >
using Limits_ = std::numeric_limits<Type>;

auto varname = Limits_<int64_t>::max();
```

or

```
template< class Type >
constexpr auto max_of() -> Type { return std::numeric_limits<Type>::max(); }

auto varname = max_of<int64_t>();
```

In C++14 and later you can make `max_of` a template variable, which for some reason that I've never seen explained, some people prefer.

Answer (score 3):

And just for completeness, skirting on the edge of legality:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template<class T>
  T biggest(T&)
{
  return std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
}

int main()
{
  std::int64_t i = biggest(i);
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I actually think this is the most concise way. What do you think is not legal here?

Comment: @MarcinZukowski it’s legal, but it only takes one maintainer to use the argument’s value in some way and it becomes UB.

Answer (score 1):

What about auto?

```
auto varname = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max();
```

There is only one place mentioning the type.